# How can I ensure that a Rust vector only contains alternating types?

Tags: data-structures, types, rust

I have a set of data that alternates between A and B. These are all valid choices:

- `A -> B -> A`
- `A -> B -> A -> B`
- `B -> A -> B`
- `B -> A -> B -> A`

I want to leverage the type system to make sure the alternating property is checked at compile time while maintaining good performance.

### Solution 1: linked list

```rust
struct A {
    // data
    next: Option<B>,
}

struct B {
    // data
    next: Option<Box<A>>,
}
```

The problem is that the performance of this data structure will be poor at best. Linked lists have frequent cache misses, and for iterating the data structure this is quite bad.

### Solution 2: Vec + enum

```rust
enum Types {
    A(DataA),
    B(DataB),
}

type Data = Vec<Types>;
```

With this solution, cache locality is much better, so yay for performance. However, this does not prevent putting 2 `A`s side-by-side. There is also the fact that one needs to check the type at each iteration, while it is not needed because of the informal definition.

### Solution 3: Combination

```rust
struct A {
    // data, default in first link = empty
    b: Option<B>,
}

struct B {
    // data
}

type Data = Vec<A>;
```

This combines the cache locality of the `Vec` with the type verification of the linked list. It is quite ugly, and one needs to check the first value to verify if it really is an `A`, or an empty container for the next `B`.

### The question

Is there a data structure that allows compile-time type verification, while maintaining cache locality and avoiding extra allocation?

Comment: You need a triple: a vector of pairs (A, B), an optional leftover B (as the first element) and an optional leftover A (as the last element).

Comment: Does that mean the length of the vec can only be 3 or 4, or were those examples just illustrative of the alternation?

Comment: It was only illustrative. Caring for performance with 4 elements would be over-optimizing big time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To store alternating types in a way that the type system enforces and has reasonable efficiency, you can use a tuple: `Vec<(X, Y)>`.

Your situation also requires

- Storing an extra leading value in an `Option` to handle starting with `Y`
- Storing an extra trailing value in an `Option` to handle ending with `X`

```
use either::Either; // 1.5.2
use std::iter;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Data<X, Y> {
    head: Option<Y>,
    pairs: Vec<(X, Y)>,
    tail: Option<X>,
}

impl<X, Y> Data<X, Y> {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Either<&X, &Y>> {
        let head = self.head.iter().map(Either::Right);

        let pairs = self.pairs.iter().flat_map(|(a, b)| {
            let a = iter::once(Either::Left(a));
            let b = iter::once(Either::Right(b));
            a.chain(b)
        });

        let tail = self.tail.iter().map(Either::Left);

        head.chain(pairs).chain(tail)
    }
}
```

That being said, you are going to have ergonomic issues *somewhere*. For example, you can't just `push` an `Either<X, Y>` because the previously pushed value might be of the same type. Creating the entire structure at once might be the simplest direction:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;

fn main() {
    let data = Data {
        head: Some(B),
        pairs: vec![(A, B)],
        tail: None,
    };

    println!("{:?}", data.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to do it! And yes, the collection is going to be created at once and then iterated over multiple time, so it should be ok from the point of view of ergonomics.

Comment: If A and B have  different sizes/alignment, it would be more efficient to store each in its own Vec.

Comment: @PeterHall I think that deserves it's own answer! The downside I see to that is that the cache locality will be decreased, which the OP mentioned as a concern. However, your solution should have lower total memory usage. It'd be tough to tell which is more performant without benchmarks.

Comment: @Shepmaster: why do you think that the cache locality will be decreased? Iterating over both vectors in lockstep would still fill up the cache lines

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I don't have a great intuition for these kinds of things, I suppose. I was mostly thinking that it would ping-pong between fetching `A` and `B`. If the prefetcher is smart enough to pull some of both, that's cool.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a data structure that allows compile-time type verification, while maintaining cache locality and avoiding extra allocation?

You can use Rust's type system to enforce that items of each type are added in alternating order. The general strategy is to capture the type of the first item and also the previous item in the type of the whole structure and make different methods available according to the "current" type. When the previous item was an `X`, only the methods for adding a `Y` will be available, and vice versa.

I'm using two `Vec`s rather than a `Vec` of tuples. Depending on your data types, this *could* result in better memory adjacency, but that really depends on how you end up iterating.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::fmt;

struct Left;
struct Right;
struct Empty;

struct AlternatingVec<L, R, P = Empty, S = Empty> {
    lefts: Vec<L>,
    rights: Vec<R>,
    prev: PhantomData<P>,
    start: PhantomData<S>,
}

impl<L, R> AlternatingVec<L, R, Empty, Empty> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        AlternatingVec {
            lefts: Vec::new(),
            rights: Vec::new(),
            prev: PhantomData,
            start: PhantomData,
        } 
    }
}
```

The types `Left`, `Right` and `Empty` are for "tagging" if the previous and start values correspond to values in the left or right collection, or if that collection is empty. Initially both collections are empty, so both `P` (the previously added value) and `S` (the start value) are `Empty`.

Next, a utility method for changing the types. It doesn't look like it does much, but we'll use it in combination with type inference to produce copies of the data structure, but with the phantom types changed.

```
impl<L, R, P, S> AlternatingVec<L, R, P, S> {    
    fn change_type<P2, S2>(self) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, P2, S2> {
        AlternatingVec {
            lefts: self.lefts,
            rights: self.rights,
            prev: PhantomData,
            start: PhantomData,
        } 
    }
}
```

In practice, the compiler is smart enough that this method does nothing at runtime.

These two traits define operations on the left and right collections respectively:

```
trait LeftMethods<L, R, S> {
    fn push_left(self, val: L) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Left, S>;
}

trait RightMethods<L, R, S> {
    fn push_right(self, val: R) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Right, S>;
}
```

We will implement those for the times we want them to be callable: `RightMethods` should only be available if the previous item was a "left" or if there are no items added so far. `LeftMethods` should be implemented if the previous items was a "right" or if there are no items added so far.

```
impl<L, R> LeftMethods<L, R, Left> for AlternatingVec<L, R, Empty, Empty> {
    fn push_left(mut self, val: L) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Left, Left> {
        self.lefts.push(val);
        self.change_type()
    }
}

impl<L, R, S> LeftMethods<L, R, S> for AlternatingVec<L, R, Right, S> {
    fn push_left(mut self, val: L) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Left, S> {
        self.lefts.push(val);
        self.change_type()
    }
}

impl<L, R> RightMethods<L, R, Right> for AlternatingVec<L, R, Empty, Empty> {
    fn push_right(mut self, val: R) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Right, Right> {
        self.rights.push(val);
        self.change_type()
    }
}

impl<L, R, S> RightMethods<L, R, S> for AlternatingVec<L, R, Left, S> {
    fn push_right(mut self, val: R) -> AlternatingVec<L, R, Right, S> {
        self.rights.push(val);
        self.change_type()
    }
}
```

These methods don't do much except call `push` on the correct inner `Vec`, and then use `change_type` to make the type reflect the signature.

The compiler forces you to call `push_left` and `push_right` alternately:

```
fn main() {
    let v = AlternatingVec::new()
        .push_left(true)
        .push_right(7)
        .push_left(false)
        .push_right(0)
        .push_left(false);
}
```

This complex structure leads to a lot more work in general. For example, `Debug` is fiddly to implement in a nice way. I made a version with a `Debug` impl, but it's getting a bit too long for Stack Overflow. You can see it here:

- https://gist.github.com/peterjoel/2ffe8b7f5ad7c649f61c580ac7dabc67